# Alternative to performSelector in Swift?

Tags: swift, performselector

The `performSelector` family of methods [are not available in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/interactingwithobjective-capis.html). So how can you call a method on an `@objc` object, where the method to be called is chosen at runtime, and not known at compile time? `NSInvocation` is apparently also not available in Swift.

I know that in Swift, you can send any method (for which there is an `@objc` method declaration visible) to the type `AnyObject`, similar to `id` in Objective-C. However, that still requires you to hard-code the method name at compile-time. Is there a way to dynamically choose it at runtime?

Comment: Rethink your approach. In my code a closure solved it.

Comment: Still you can do this, find my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126261/swift-alternative-to-performselectoronmainthread/31853168#31853168

Comment: @matt Fine, please rethink pyramid of doom for me then, thanks.

Comment: @turingtested I rethink it as a sequence of `guard` statements. :)

Answer (score 18):

Using closures

```
class A {
    var selectorClosure: (() -> Void)?

    func invoke() {
        self.selectorClosure?()
    }
}

var a = A()
a.selectorClosure = { println("Selector called") }
a.invoke()
```

Note that this is nothing new, even in Obj-C the new APIs prefer using blocks over `performSelector` (compare `UIAlertView` which uses `respondsToSelector:` and `performSelector:` to call delegate methods, with the new `UIAlertController`).

Using `performSelector:` is always unsafe and doesn't play well with ARC (hence the ARC warnings for `performSelector:`).

Comment: Looks good, but you can rewrite your `selectorClosure` property like this (note that `nil` assignment for an optional is implicit): `var selectorClosure: (() -> Void)?`

Answer (score 16):

As of Xcode 7, the full family of performSelector methods are available in Swift, including `performSelectorOnMainThread()` and `performSelectorInBackground()`. Enjoy!

Comment: @RoiMulia yes, so long as you compile with Xcode 7+

Answer (score 15):

#### Approach A

Use `NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector`, good thing about this approach is that we can attach object to the message. Example code in ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let delay = 2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    var time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(Selector("greetings:"), toTarget:self, withObject: "sunshine")
        })
}

func greetings(object: AnyObject?) {
    println("greetings world")
    println("attached object: \(object)")
}
```

Console log:

> greetings world
>
> attached object: sunshine

#### Approach B

This alternative was discovered earlier, I have also tested on device and simulator. The idea is to use following method of **UIControl**:

```
func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: AnyObject!, forEvent event: UIEvent!)
```

Example code in ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    var control: UIControl = UIControl()
    control.sendAction(Selector("greetings"), to: self, forEvent: nil) // Use dispatch_after to invoke this line as block if delay is intended 
}

func greetings() {
    println("greetings world")
}
```

Console log:

> greetings world

#### Approach C

NSTimer

```
class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_ seconds: NSTimeInterval,
                                      target target: AnyObject!,
                                 selector aSelector: Selector,
                                  userInfo userInfo: AnyObject!,
                                    repeats repeats: Bool) -> NSTimer!
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems A (`dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, ...`) is the only way to dynamically call ObjC method with argument from Swift.

Comment: BTW, is it really necessary to dispatch on main queue? I.e. when you change UIView's property it might notify observer waiting for main thread event? Also, while you are dispatching on main thread it would be executed on different thread anyway.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 3.1**
For standard Swift projects closures are elegant solution already covered in [Sulthan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159063/5329717).
Invoking methods dynamically using selector string names makes sense if one depends on legacy Objective-C code / libraries or would like to invoke private API.

Only `NSObject` subclasses can receive messages, attempt to send one to a pure Swift class will result in a crash.

`#selector(mySelectorName)` can resolve typed selector names in its class source file only.
By sacrificing type checking a selector can be retrieved using `NSSelectorFromString(...)`
(*it's not safer in any way compared to* `Selector("selectorName:arg:")` *it just happens not to generate a warning*).

Calling `NSObject` subclass instance method

```
let instance : NSObject = fooReturningObjectInstance() as! NSObject
instance.perform(#selector(NSSelectorFromString("selector"))
instance.perform(#selector(NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:"), with: arg)
instance.perform(#selector(NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:Arg2:"), with: arg, with: arg2)
```

also with main thread variant:

```
instance.performSelector(onMainThread: NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:"), with: arg, waitUntilDone: false)
```

*As noted by* iOS_MIB *in* https://stackoverflow.com/a/48644264/5329717
this is **not equivalent** to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //perform selector
}
```

and background thread variant:

```
instance.performSelector(inBackground: NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:"), with: arg)
```

There are some limitations though:

- It can only take 0-2 arguments
- value type arguments like integers and selectors don't work
- can't handle returned value types
- returns objects as `Unmanaged<AnyObject>`

So this low effort approach is convenient when return result and value type arguments are not needed.

Fetching `NSObject` runtime method `IMP` allows making a typed call with proper arguments and return type.
`@convention(c)(types)->type` allows casting the `IMP` result to compatible Swift closure function.

In `@convention(c)` not all types are allowed

- For classes use Any or AnyClass
- For objects use Any or exact class type if its symbol is available
- For value types use the relevant type
- For void* use OpaquePointer

*This is by definition* **unsafe** *and if done incorrectly will result in crashes and side effects.*

Every Objective-C method on C level contains two hidden arguments to conform to `objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)` which need to be included in the function type as `@convention(c)(Any?,Selector, ... )`

```
let instance : NSObject = fooReturningObjectInstance() as! NSObject
let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:")
let methodIMP : IMP! = instance.method(for: selector)
unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,Any?)->Void).self)(instance,selector,arg)
```

These are **static** equivalents of `perform(...)`

```
NSObject.perform(NSSelectorFromString("selector"))
NSObject.perform(NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:"), with: arg)
NSObject.perform(NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:Arg2:"), with: arg, with: arg2)
NSObject.performSelector(onMainThread: NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:"), with: arg, waitUntilDone: false)
NSObject.performSelector(inBackground: NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:"), with: arg)
```

Limitations:

- All type issues mentioned previously
- The receiver class needs to have a defined symbol

Fetching runtime static method `IMP` and handling types, `@convention(c)` applies

```
let receiverClass = NSClassFromString("MyClass")
let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:")
let methodIMP : IMP! = method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod(receiverClass, selector))
let result : NSObject = unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(AnyClass?,Selector,Any?)->Any).self)(receiverClass,selector,arg) as! NSObject
```

There's no practical reason to do it, but `objc_msgSend` can be used dynamically.

```
let instance : NSObject = fooReturningObjectInstance() as! NSObject
let handle : UnsafeMutableRawPointer! = dlopen("/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", RTLD_NOW)
let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString("selectorArg:")
unsafeBitCast(dlsym(handle, "objc_msgSend"), to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector!,Any?)->Void).self)(instance,selector,arg)
dlclose(handle)
```

Same for `NSInvocation` (this is only fun exercise, **don't** do it)

```
class Test : NSObject
{
    var name : String? {
        didSet {
            NSLog("didSetCalled")
        }
    }

    func invocationTest() {
        let invocation : NSObject = unsafeBitCast(method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"), NSSelectorFromString("invocationWithMethodSignature:"))),to:(@convention(c)(AnyClass?,Selector,Any?)->Any).self)(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"),NSSelectorFromString("invocationWithMethodSignature:"),unsafeBitCast(method(for: NSSelectorFromString("methodSignatureForSelector:"))!,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,Selector)->Any).self)(self,NSSelectorFromString("methodSignatureForSelector:"),#selector(setter:name))) as! NSObject
        unsafeBitCast(class_getMethodImplementation(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"), NSSelectorFromString("setSelector:")),to:(@convention(c)(Any,Selector,Selector)->Void).self)(invocation,NSSelectorFromString("setSelector:"),#selector(setter:name))
        var localName = name
        withUnsafePointer(to: &localName) { unsafeBitCast(class_getMethodImplementation(NSClassFromString("NSInvocation"), NSSelectorFromString("setArgument:atIndex:")),to:(@convention(c)(Any,Selector,OpaquePointer,NSInteger)->Void).self)(invocation,NSSelectorFromString("setArgument:atIndex:"), OpaquePointer($0),2) }
        invocation.perform(NSSelectorFromString("invokeWithTarget:"), with: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

`perform(#selector(someSelector), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0, inModes: [.commonModes])`

Answer (score 7):

As per @JTerry answer "You don't need selectors in Swift", you can assign actual methods to variables. My solution was the following (I needed one parameter in method):

```
class SettingsMenuItem: NSObject {
    ...
    var tapFunction: ((sender: AnyObject?) -> ())?
}
```

And then in view controller I declared, assigned and run the function in this way:

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    func editProfile(sender: AnyObject?) {
        ...
    }

    ...

    menuItem.tapFunction = editProfile

    ...

    if let tapFunction = menuItem.tapFunction {
        tapFunction(sender: self)
    }


}
```

Comment: your answer is limited to selectors in general and if they are still needed in swift. But the question was about alternatives to *performSelector* which was used for async stuff, defer, wait for completion or easy and quick thread control (running on main or a background thread).

Comment: Thanks for this example, it is the first instance I found outlining how you call an "unknown" method with a know signature in Swift (which is occasionally what I want to do if I model things with dynamic methods). Much more useful than `NSInvocation` and much less error prone too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this in Swift

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:  Selector("someSelector"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


func someSelector() {
// Something after a delay
}
```

by this you can do what is performed by performSelector in Objective-C

Comment: This is not exactly the same because 1) it does it asynchronously, whereas `performSelector:` (without `afterDelay`) is synchronous; 2) it only works on a thread where we are running a run loop.

Comment: Hi @user102008 it works fine for me, now, how do I stop the timer if I set repeats to true?

Comment: @Josh `timer.invalidate()`

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this too.  I finally realized that I didn't need to use targets or selectors.  For me the solution was to assign the func to a variable and call that variable.  It even works if you call it from other classes.  Here's a quick example:

```
func Apple() ->Int
{
    let b = 45;
    return b;
}

func Orange()->Int
{
    let i = 5;
    return i;
}

func Peach()
{
    var a = Apple; // assign the var a the Apple function
    var b = Orange; // assisgn the var b to the Orange function

    let c = a(); // assign the return value of calling the 'a' or Apple function to c
    let d = b(); // assign the return value of calling the 'b' or Orange function d

    Pear(a, b)
}

func Pear(x:()->Int, y:()->Int)->Int
{
    let w = (x()+y()); // call the x function, then the y function and add the return values of each function.
    return w; // return the sum
}

Peach();
```

Comment: This worked for me. I needed function with one parameter so I declared 'selector' property like this --- var tapFunction: ((sender: AnyObject?) -> ())? --- and then declare a function as --- func actionMethod(sender: AnyObject?)

Answer (score 3):

Huh, we can use swizzling for unveil desired methods!

Just add this `extension` and prefix all calls with  symbol.

```
import Foundation

private var dispatchOnceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

private var selectors: [Selector] = [
    "performSelector:",
    "performSelector:withObject:",
    "performSelector:withObject:withObject:",
    "performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:",
    "performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:",
]

private func swizzle() {
    dispatch_once(&dispatchOnceToken) {
        for selector: Selector in selectors {
            let selector = Selector("\(selector)")
            let method = class_getInstanceMethod(NSObject.self, selector)

            class_replaceMethod(
                NSObject.self,
                selector,
                method_getImplementation(method),
                method_getTypeEncoding(method)
            )
        }
    }
}

extension NSObject {

    func performSelector(selector: Selector) -> AnyObject? {
        swizzle()
        return self.performSelector(selector)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        swizzle()
        return self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object1: AnyObject?, withObject object2: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        swizzle()
        return self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object1, withObject: object2)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object: AnyObject?, afterDelay delay: NSTimeInterval, inModes modes: [AnyObject?]?) {
        swizzle()
        self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object, afterDelay: delay, inModes: modes)
    }

    func performSelector(selector: Selector, withObject object: AnyObject?, afterDelay delay: NSTimeInterval) {
        swizzle()
        self.performSelector(selector, withObject: object, afterDelay: delay)
    }

}
```

Comment: hey.. did I just see a Rocket..!!! :) just kidding..  works like a charm.. thanks.

Comment: Yeah... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the actual syntax for dispatch queue is as follow.

```
dispatch_after(1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.loadData() // call your method.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes (especially if you are using `target/action` pattern) you may have to use method `-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]` (for iOS), so in Swift it can be somethings like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    .sendAction(someSelector, to: someObject, from: antotherObject, forEvent: someEvent)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly since when, but Apple brought back performSelector in Xcode 7.1.1 (At least that's the version I'm using).

In my app I'm currently building, I'm calling various functions with similar functionNames in a UIView generated from CoreAnimator (great app, BTW), so performSelector comes in very handy.  Here's how I use it:

```
//defines the function name dynamically.  the variables "stepN" and "dir" are defined elsewhere. 
let AnimMethod = "addStep\(stepN)\(dir)Animation"

//prepares the selector with the function name above           
let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString(AnimMethod)

//calls the said function in UIView named "meter"            
meter.performSelector(selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation, where selector is constructed with string literal that comes from plist file.
So the fastest way to perform some selector in swift was solved with next code

```
var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1000, target: self, selector: Selector(someString), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
timer.fire()
timer.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

A real world example in swift of "Matej Ukmar's" comment to "J Terry's" answer:

```
class Button {
    var title:String = "The big button"
    var selector: ((sender: AnyObject?, type:String) -> ())?/*this holds any method assigned to it that has its type signature*/
    func click(){
        selector!(sender: self,type: "click")/*call the selector*/
    }
    func hover(){
        selector!(sender: self,type: "hover")/*call the selector*/
    }
}
class View {
    var button = Button()
    init(){
        button.selector = handleSelector/*assign a method that will receive a call from the selector*/
    }
    func handleSelector(sender: AnyObject?,type:String) {
        switch type{
            case "click": Swift.print("View.handleSelector() sender: " + String(sender!.dynamicType) + ", title: " + String((sender as! Button).title) + ", type: " + type)
            case "hover": Swift.print("View.handleSelector() sender: " + String(sender!.dynamicType) + ", title: " + String((sender as! Button).title) + ", type: " + type)
            default:break;
        }
    }
}
let view:View = View()
view.button.click()/*Simulating button click*/
view.button.hover()/*Simulating button hover*/
//Output: View.handleSelector() sender: Button, title: The big button, type: click
//Output: View.handleSelector() sender: Button, title: The big button, type: hover
```

Answer (score 0):

just another input for that topic.

From time to time I had to call functions/methods "indirectly". Example: calling individual functions for specific cells. I often use arrays of structs to define tabelView behavior.

I used *PerformSelector* etc. before, but that always looks "strange" in a swift program, so I did some research and since then, I used the indirect function calls.

This is a quick example of my playground to test the syntax and the behavior ... (xCode 9.4.1)

```
// Test for indirect function calls

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// functions we want to call inderectly
func function1() {
    print("function1 active")
}

func function2() {
    print("function2 active")
}

func function3() {
    print("function3 active")
}

func function4(_ parameter: Int)  {

    print("function4 use the parameter: \(parameter)")
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// data structures

// a struct to build array items
struct functionCallTestStruct {

    // struct properties
    let what: String            // a string as an example for other variables
    let functionToCall : ()     // the function as an array element
    var functionWithParameter : (Int) -> () // the function as an array element
    let parameterForFunction : Int


    // Initializer
    init(_ what: String,
         _ functionToCall: (),
         _ functionWithParameter: @escaping (Int) -> (),
         _ parameterForFunction: Int) {

        self.what = what
        self.functionToCall = functionToCall
        self.functionWithParameter = functionWithParameter
        self.parameterForFunction = parameterForFunction
    }
}

// the array which holds the functions we want to call
let functionTestArray : [functionCallTestStruct] = [

    functionCallTestStruct("We will call the first function",  function1(), function4(_:), 10),
    functionCallTestStruct("We will call the second function", function2(), function4(_:), 11),
    functionCallTestStruct("We will call the third function",  function3(), function4(_:), 12),
]

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Test program

// a loop over the array
for i in 0 ..< functionTestArray.count {

    // print explanation (be aware: print is quite lame, .. see the output ;-))
    print(functionTestArray[i].what)

    // and with this we indirectly call the functions
    functionTestArray[i].functionToCall
    let myParameter = functionTestArray[i].parameterForFunction
    functionTestArray[i].functionWithParameter(myParameter)
}
```

gives the output:

```
function1 active
function2 active
function3 active
We will call the first function
function4 use the parameter: 10
We will call the second function
function4 use the parameter: 11
We will call the third function
function4 use the parameter: 12
```

funny fact: the print of the String (what) is slower that the function call with a print ... Which is also a warning: Don't trust on sequence with this tactic

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really explain what your where trying to actually achieve, so here's sone ideas that might lead your to a solution.
Firstly, and I would encourage you to to do this unless you haven to, but you can dynamical generate a selection from a String in swift

```
Selector("myMehodA:")
Selector("myMehodB:")
```

But functions are first rate objects in swift so why not just use a dictionary

```
func bMethod() { print("B") }

let dict = ["aThing": { print("A") },
            "bThing": bMethod]

dict["aThing"]?()
dict["bThing"]?()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the following solution:

```
// method will be called after delay
func method1() {

    ......    
}

// to replace performSelector
// delay 100 ms
let time : dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSEC_PER_MSEC/(USEC_PER_SEC*10)))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.method1()
})
```

Comment: the question wasn't about a delay