# Dynamic method invocation with swift using a string

Tags: swift, dynamic-programming

Does swift support the ability to call a method using a string?

I'll steal a great example from http://pilky.me/21/ to illustrate what I'd like to be able to do in swift. This is a trivial example, but for some design patterns this capability if very powerful and is supported in many other popular languages.

```
- (void)parseObject:(id)object {
    for (id data in object) {
        if ([[data type] isEqualToString:@"String"]) {
            [self parseString:[data value]]; 
        } else if ([[data type] isEqualToString:@"Number"]) {
            [self parseNumber:[data value]];
        } else if ([[data type] isEqualToString:@"Array"]) {
            [self parseArray:[data value]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parseObjectDynamic:(id)object {
    for (id data in object) {
        [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"parse%@:", [data type]]) withObject:[data value]];
    }
}

- (void)parseString:(NSString *)aString {}
- (void)parseNumber:(NSString *)aNumber {}
- (void)parseArray:(NSString *)aArray {}
```

> As you can see, you can replace 7 line if statement with a single
>   line. And the benefit is that if you need to support a new type in the
>   future, you just add the new method, rather than have to remember to
>   add an extra else if to your main parse method.

I understand you can call a block dynamically.

There is a similar SO question here, but does not address how to do it in swift with strings:
[Alternative to performSelector in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift)

Comment: In Swift, there would be 2 good ways I see doing this. First is to use `Generics`, second is to use a function that returns one of those functions for you. The second method can make use of the awesome Switch mechanics in Swift

Comment: Hey Jack,  the example shown above is trivial.  Yes, a generic would work for the example above.  But there are other reasons you would want to call methods by string name to reduce amount of ceremony required when doing dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like performSelect isn't part of the runloop with Swift. It might just come in a later seed
[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/performSelector:target:argument:order:modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/performSelector%3atarget%3aargument%3aorder%3amodes):

Comment: Also relevant is http://bit.ly/1i5AE05 NSObject performSelector reference.  Yet, I still wonder if there is another way to achieve the same thing?