# Invoke target action in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift, how do I execute the Cocoa target-action pattern with a selector determined at runtime?

The specifics at hand:
My code receives a `UIBarButtonItem`, and it needs invoke the action that button represents.  In Objective-C, it's straightforward:

```
UIBarButtonItem* button = ...;
[button.target performSelector: button.action withObject: self];
```

In Swift, `performSelector:` is not exposed for type/memory safety reasons.  I can't create a Swift closure since I don't know the button.action at compile time.  Any other technique for invoking the action?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was answered in the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998951):

> Use `UIApplication.sendAction(_:to:from:forEvent:)`. Technically, you
>   should be using that even in Objective-C, because it understands the
>   various kinds of parameters an action can take and passes them for
>   you.

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    .sendAction(button.action, to: button.target,
                from: self, forEvent: nil)
```

It has the same effect as @vladof's answer, but it saves allocating the UIControl.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is a method in Objective C class **TestClass** that returns a UIBarButtonItem:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)getBarButtonItem
{
    UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    bar.target = self;
    bar.action = @selector(help);
    return bar;
}

- (void)help
{
    NSLog(@"Help offered");
}
```

In Swift:

```
var testClass = TestClass()
var barButtonItem = testClass.getBarButtonItem()
var button: UIButton = UIButton()
button.sendAction(barButtonItem.action, to: barButtonItem.target, forEvent: nil)
```

Console log:

> 2014-07-06 23:49:49.942 TestApp [53986:2552835] Help offered

Also note that we can instantiate **UIControl** instead of UIButton.

Comment: Alternative: (Just to keep the posts in-sync) There is another approach to invoke action on target using `NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector`, please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24602971/2920335).