# What is alternative to performSelector in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, performselector

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(showMainView)];

I am using an API having the code above in a iOS swift project, and couldn't find how to write it into a proper swift code.  It seems swift doesn't have function named performSelector, so what can I do to make it work in swift?

Comment: have you checked this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift

Comment: Why on earth are you calling performSelector in the first place when you pass in the selector? Why not [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate showMainView] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
appDelegate.showMainView()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I put the name of class given in API after 'as' and it works.