# What is the correct way to use a performSelector with returning value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, selector, performselector

I'm building a Framework and a Testing-app in Swift and I was wondering what is the best way to use a performSelector in Swift, because in Objective-C I could use:

```
NSDictionary *values = [framework performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"getValues")];
```

So I want to call the private method `getValues()` of my framework and the method `getValues()` returns a `NSDictionary`.

Now I've been searching around and I've found some alternatives for `performSelector`:

```
- NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:  Selector("method"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
 - NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(Selector("method"), toTarget:self, withObject: "sunshine")
        })
 - UIControl.sendAction(Selector("method"), to: self, forEvent: nil)
```

But none of them are able to return values, so my question is, what is the best way to implement this in swift?

I also found this: 
https://gist.github.com/smugen/6710ec5741795451f048 , but I want to stick to pure swift

Comment: The performSelector family of methods are not available in Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift

Comment: the `–performSelector...` methods can cause leak, that is why those are not available in Swift, on the other hand the `NSTimer`, `NSThread` or `UIControl`'s implementation is probably based on Objective-C not on Swift.