# Swift perform to selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, performselector

I found here that *performSelector: withObject:* is not available in swift,  Can someone help I am trying to convert app written in Obj C to Swift, any of founded answers didn't help. This is the code

```
[newTopViewController performSelector:@selector(setSalesDocumentType:)withObject:@(menuItem.salesDocumentType)];
```

Tried every answer here [Alternative to performSelector in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift) , nothing helps. NSTimer doesn't have property *withObject:*, main thread doesn't help too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to don more Thing just do this :-

```
DataShowViewController.performSelectorOnMainThread("selector:", withObject: AnyObject?(), waitUntilDone: false, modes: nil)
```

In AnyObject You Can Pass Your Object.......

Comment: Does not recognize performSelectorOnMainThread

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var timer = NSTimer.ScheduledTimerWithTimerInterval(1.0,target:self selector:Selector("functionName") userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
DataShowViewController.performSelector("YourSelector:", onThread: hereIsYOurThred, withObject: HereIsYOurObj, waitUntilDone: true, modes: yourModes)
```