# How do you use perform(#selector(setter:)) to set the value of a property using swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, performselector

I'm trying to run this code but it's yielding unexpected results.

```
class Test: NSObject {
    @objc var property: Int = 0
}

var t = Test()

t.perform(#selector(setter: Test.property), with: 100)
print(t.property)
```

The value being printed is some junk number `-5764607523034233277`. How can I set the value of a property using the perform method?

Comment: Curious why you are trying to use `perform(_:with:)` at all.

Comment: It can only pass objects, you would have to make your property an `NSNumber`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `performSelector:withObject:` method requires an object argument, so Swift is converting the primitive 100 to an object reference.

The `setProperty:` method (which is what `#selector(setter: Test.property)` evaluates to) takes a primitive `NSInteger` argument. So it is treating the object reference as an integer.

Because of this mismatch, you cannot invoke `setProperty:` using `performSelector:withObject:` in a meaningful way.

You can, however, use `setValue:forKey:` and a `#keyPath` instead, because Key-Value Coding knows how to convert objects to primitives:

```
t.setValue(100, forKey: #keyPath(Test.property))
```

Comment: That's a good answer but don't forget that swift doesn't exactly have primitive types. I get what you are saying though.

Comment: If you wanted to use keypaths, you can also do `t[keyPath: \Test.property] = 42`. This is a strongly typed way of doing it. (I just wanted to see how many different Rob's could contribute to one answer.)

Comment: @Rob I actually need a very generic way to set values on a variety of different objects. Because KeyPaths are strongly typed they aren't going to work for me. I just discovered that setValue and value(forKey:) will allow me to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `perform(_:with:)` to do that since `Int` is not a `NSObject` subclass which is necessary for the arg. To specify the type you can workaround it with:

```
let setterSelector = #selector(setter: Test.property)
let setterIMP = t.method(for: setterSelector)
//Invoking setter
unsafeBitCast(setterIMP,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,Int)->Void).self)(t, setterSelector,100)

let getterSelector = #selector(getter: Test.property)
let getterIMP = t.method(for: getterSelector)
//Invoking getter
let intValue = unsafeBitCast(getterIMP,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector)->Int).self)(t, getterSelector)
```

You can find more details and examples in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/5329717%20here)