# Swift: A function with a Selector argument returns an unmanaged<AnyObject>?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the use of -

`func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> unmanaged<AnyObject>!`

in iOS?

- To call a method of a class?
- To add a selector method?
- To add a class delegate?
- To define a class? (I doubt it's this)

I was originally thinking that it it was to add a selector method, but after looking at it some more I think it may be "to call a method of a class." Selectors are used for target/action paradigms where I kick something off and when the event fires or finishes then it wants to fire off some kind of action method. 
In this example do I pass it a parameter of a selector function then at the end of this "perform" function, I am returning an unmanaged object of any type? Does that even make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the method from `NSObjectProtocol` which is from the Objective-C runtime?

Comment: @rmaddy --> I don't know. This was asked on a quiz that I was taking and I didn't have any other information for this question.

Comment: @rmaddy -> If the method was referring to the NSObjectProtocol, would it have a different meaning or do something that I wouldn't normally expect?

Comment: Basically it's something you would very rarely, if ever, use in Swift. It should rarely be used directly any more in Objective-C.

Comment: Indeed this used to be forbidden in Swift, and even now should be avoided, as Swift provides better ways. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift this is basically useless. It's bridged from Objective-C, where it used to be very useful (before ARC), but now [it's a bit tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown).

The point of it is to send a message by name and get a result. Generally speaking that translates to calling a method of that name.

Comment: So basically this is "calling a method" and returning some data type? Not a nice way of doing it, but a long, obnoxious way of doing it?

Comment: It's only obnoxious in Swift. In ObjC, it's pretty elegant, and is the core tool used for all the target/action features like UIButton, NSTimer, and the like.

Comment: Thanks! I have been writing more Swift code than Objective-C.

Comment: Is this method just short-hand for the ObjC runtime APIs like `class_getMethodImplementation(AnyClass?, Selector)`?

Comment: @Alexander It's a wrapper around `objc_msgSend`. You can see the source code for it here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-723/runtime/NSObject.mm.auto.html