# How to invoke a Selector in Swift with more than 2 arguments

Tags: swift, nsdocument

I'm overriding NSDocumentControllers `reviewUnsavedDocuments(withAlertTitle:cancellable:delegate:didReviewAllSelector:contextInfo:)` in Swift. The documentation says that the didReviewAllSelector has this signature, note it has 3 arguments:

```
- (void)documentController:(NSDocumentController *)docController  didReviewAll: (BOOL)didReviewAll contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

So I need to invoke the `selector` on `delegate` with three arguments. The problem I'm facing is that I cant seem to find a neat way to do this in swift.

The closest match I can find is that NSObject has `perform(aSelector:with:with:)` taking 2 parameters. Is there something like this with 3 arguments?

Examaple code

```
func reviewUnsavedDocuments(withAlertTitle title: String?, cancellable: Bool, delegate: Any?, didReviewAllSelector: Selector?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

  if let object = delegate as? NSObject {
    object.perform(didReviewAllSelector, with: self, with: true ... and
              now I need to add contextInfo as a third paramenter here?
  }
}
```

I have done this successfully in obj-c using NSInvocation. But thats not available from swift :(

Comment: I don't have control of `delegate` or `selector`. It's passed to me from a framework. This is a system method I'm overriding on NSDocumentController.

Comment: I ended up writing an obj-c class that uses NSInvocation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `@convention(c)` available since Swift 3

```
let methodIMP: IMP! = object.method(for: didReviewAllSelector)
unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector,Any?,Bool, OpaquePointer)->Void).self)(object,didReviewAllSelector,self,true,OpaquePointer(contextInfo))
```

More info and examples covered in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/5329717).

I believe `OpaquePointer` should work for your 3rd arg, but let me know if you run into any problems.