# performSelector from swift to objc with selector parameter not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector

oc code

```c
@implementation TestSelector

+ (void)test:(SEL)sel {
    NSString *selName = NSStringFromSelector(sel);
    NSLog(@"%@", selName);
}

@end
```

swift code

```swift
let sel = #selector(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.collectionView(_:layout:insetForSectionAt:))
TestSelector.perform(#selector(TestSelector.test(_:)), with: sel)
```

`test:` method from `TestSelector` log nil

```
2020-03-26 16:41:08.764739+0800 TestSelector[30954:774345] (null)
```

lldb for sel

```
(lldb) po sel
collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:

(lldb) p sel
(SEL) $1 = "\xffffffe8\xffffff96\xffffffbf\xffffff89\xffffffff\x7f"

(lldb) po NSStringFromSelector(sel);
 nil
```

Answer (score 1):

From Apple

```
func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
```

doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418764-perform

> Sends a message to the receiver with **an object** as the argument.

Your `SEL` sel argument is *not an object*. Internally it's actually a `char*` pointer. So you **can't** use

```
TestSelector.perform(#selector(TestSelector.test(_:)), with: sel)
```

this way.

If you'd like to keep using `perform(_:with:)` you'd have to do some changes in your code. An example workaround would look like this:

In the Objective-C part

```
@implementation TestSelector
+ (void)test:(NSString*)selectorName {
    NSLog(@"%@", selectorName);
}
@end
```

and in the Swift part:

```
let sel = #selector(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.collectionView(_:layout:insetForSectionAt:))
TestSelector.perform(#selector(TestSelector.test(_:)), with: NSStringFromSelector(sel))
```

*However* if would like to keep your original Objective-C code with `SEL` arg you'd have invoke the selector in Swift using `@convention(c)`. I covered details of it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158427/alternative-to-performselector-in-swift/43714950#43714950)

For your particular case the Swift invocation would look like this:

```
let selArg = #selector(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.collectionView(_:layout:insetForSectionAt:))
let selector = #selector(TestSelector.test(_:))
let methodIMP: IMP! = method_getImplementation(class_getClassMethod(TestSelector.self, selector))
unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(AnyClass?,Selector,Selector)->Void).self)(TestSelector.self,selector, selArg)
```