# Dynamically instanciating ObjC class in Swift (with NSClassFromString?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I have an ObjC class with an init method

```
-(instancetype) initWithApiKey: (NSString *) key order: (NSNumber *) order
```

In ObjC I dynamically create it with the following code:

```
id classAllocation = [NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc];
NSObject * classInstance = [classAllocation performSelector:@selector(initWithApiKey:order:) 
withObject:@"mykey" withObject:@1];
```

But how would I do the same in Swift?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you do it this way? Why not simply call the initializer? Or is rhis just a simplified example for the question?

Comment: Can't you just call it from Swift? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring

You need to show what exactly did you try in Swift and how it didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to use performSelector in ObjC, BTW.  You can just call ```[[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc] initWithApiKey:@"mykey" order:@1]```.  You can dynamically create objects with the empty initializer from Swift ( ```let classObject = NSClassFromString("MyClass"); let classInstance = classObject.init()``` from Swift, but not sure you can do any arbitrary init method that way.  You may need to implement a wrapper function or class method which is then bridged and callable from Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let allocatedObject = NSClassFromString("MyClass")?.alloc() as? NSObject {
    let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString("initWithApiKey:order:")
    let methodIMP: IMP! = allocatedObject.method(for: selector)
    let objectAfterInit = unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(AnyObject?,Selector,NSString,NSNumber)->NSObject).self)(allocatedObject,selector,"mykey", NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1))
}
```

More examples with details in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/5329717)

Comment: I've ended up with a similar solution
``` if let allocatedObject = NSClassFromString("MyClass")?.alloc() as? NSObject {
                let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString("initWithApiKey:order:")
                let obj = allocatedObject.init()
                if (obj.responds(to: selector)) == true {
                    obj.perform(selector, with:"key", order:0);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can also do the following to avoid using strings:

`(MyClass.self as AnyClass).alloc() as! MyClass`