# How to get the actual type of a swift struct in the disguise of a `__SwiftValue`

Tags: swift, value-type, any, encoder-decoder

I'm using YapDatabase to encode/decode my Swift value types. After decoding, the type information seems to be *lost*, that is `type(of:element)` returns `__SwiftValue` instead of, e.g., `Reservation`.

If I call `po element` in the debugger though, it seems that the type information is still retained:

```
(lldb) po element 
SecureTruckParking.Reservation(reservationId: 12625, accessInformations: [SecureTruckParking.AccessInformation(accessInformationId: 12706, accessTypeId: 1, accessTypeKey: Optional("1"), accessTypeTenantKey: Optional("ROOT"), encodedValue: "XXX", displayedValue: "XXX"), SecureTruckParking.AccessInformation(accessInformationId: 12707, accessTypeId: 51, accessTypeKey: Optional("51"), accessTypeTenantKey: Optional("ROOT"), encodedValue: "918296", displayedValue: "918296")], customerId: 3156, areaId: 552, productId: 1004, state: "PENDING", startTime: 2020-09-10 08:23:00 +0000, endTime: 2020-09-11 08:23:00 +0000, earliestEntryTime: 2020-09-10 08:23:00 +0000, latestExitTime: 2020-09-11 08:23:00 +0000, totalAmount: 2750.0, currency: "€", netPrice: 2311.0, taxPrice: 439.0, invoiceItems: [SecureTruckParking.InvoiceItem(amount: 1, itemText: "Parkplatzreservierung, 10.09.2020 10:23 - 11.09.2020 10:23 \nREWE Logistikzentrum Neu-Isenburg -> REWE Logistikzentrum Neu-Isenburg", netPrice: 2311.0, taxPrice: 439.0, taxRate: 19.0)], productAttributes: [SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "early_bird_count", value: Optional("1"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "early_bird_count", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "DETAILS", value: nil, definitionId: nil), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "INFO_DETAILS", value: nil, definitionId: nil), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "early_bird", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "early_bird", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "manualBackofficeCancellationConfirmation", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "manualBackofficeCancellationConfirmation", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "manualBackofficeCancellationConfirmationThreshold", value: Optional("1"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "manualBackofficeCancellationConfirmationThreshold", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "product_icon", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "product_icon", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "product_image", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "product_image", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "product_tariff_group", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "product_tariff_group", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading_dates_fixed", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading_dates_fixed", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading_immediate", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading_immediate", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading_mail", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading_mail", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading_price_surcharge", value: Optional("false"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading_price_surcharge", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "early_bird_duration", value: Optional("1440"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "early_bird_duration", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "recurring_max_trips", value: Optional("1"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "recurring_max_trips", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading_mail_max_lead_time", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading_mail_max_lead_time", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "upgrading_mail_min_lead_time", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "upgrading_mail_min_lead_time", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "bstp_product_type", value: Optional("Reservation"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "bstp_product_type", tenant: "ROOT")))], areaAttributes: [SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "product_icon", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "product_icon", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "product_image", value: nil, definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "product_image", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "Parking_Area_UST", value: Optional("22222222222222"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "Parking_Area_UST", tenant: "MAN_BOSCH"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "ipaw_id", value: Optional("4651"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "ipaw_id", tenant: "ROOT"))), SecureTruckParking.Attribute(key: "bstp_area_type", value: Optional("PROFESSIONAL"), definitionId: Optional(SecureTruckParking.DefinitionId(key: "bstp_area_type", tenant: "ROOT")))])
```

What is this `__SwiftValue` and is there a way to get the actual type (besides any horrible approaches of parsing the `String(describing: element`)?

Comment: Did you try printing `element.self` ?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR Yes, this prints the same as `po element`, also `po type(of: any.self)` leads again to `__SwiftValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you're seeing the `__SwiftValue` because the `struct` has been wrapped with `as AnyObject` cast. You can easily verify this yourself:

```
struct TestStruct {}
let ourStruct = TestStruct()
let structSwiftValue = ourStruct as AnyObject
print(type(of: ourStruct))
print(type(of: structSwiftValue))
```

outputs:

```
TestStruct
__SwiftValue
```

Good discussion on the topic: https://forums.swift.org/t/anyobject/35659/9

Now to the essence of your question, unfortunately I believe there's no convenient public API for the time being that would allow you to extract original metadata `Type` from `__SwiftValue`.

Still the topic is too interesting not to venture into private API territory for educational purposes.

Let's begin with `__SwiftValue` itself https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftValue.mm

There is promising API available through obj-c:

```
// Private methods for debugging purposes.

- (const Metadata *)_swiftTypeMetadata {
  return getSwiftValueTypeMetadata(self);
}
- (id /* NSString */)_swiftTypeName {
  TypeNamePair typeName
    = swift_getTypeName(getSwiftValueTypeMetadata(self), true);
  id str = swift_stdlib_NSStringFromUTF8(typeName.data, typeName.length);
  return [str autorelease];
}
- (const OpaqueValue *)_swiftValue {
  return getValueFromSwiftValue(self).second;
}
```

Let's start with something fairly simple:

```
print(structSwiftValue.value(forKey: "_swiftTypeName")!)
```

outputs:

```
ModuleName.TestStruct
```

Just a `String` type, but not bad for starters. The next promising candidate to explore seems:

```
- (const Metadata *)_swiftTypeMetadata()
```

We can call it like this (*in depth details on this particular way of invoking selectors in Swift can be found* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/5329717))

```
let selector: Selector = NSSelectorFromString("_swiftTypeMetadata")
let methodIMP: IMP! = structSwiftValue.method(for: selector)
let metadataPtr = unsafeBitCast(methodIMP,to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector)->OpaquePointer).self)(structSwiftValue,selector)
```

Now the challenge is to somehow make use of `Metadata *` (i.e. the `OpaquePointer` after bridging to Swift) in a `type(of:)` manner.

I found a way to do it, albeit a very hacky one.
We begin with a metadata `Type` variable of some dummy object or struct (doesn't really matter). The general idea is eventually we'd like to replace the metadata  pointer with one we got from our previous stage. I noticed the result of `type(of:)` yields a pointer pointing at the metadata, so there's extra level of indirection, we will have to accommodate for that:

```
var placeholderTypeVar: Any.Type = type(of: NSObject())
print(placeholderTypeVar)
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &placeholderTypeVar) {
    let unsafePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    unsafePtr.pointee = metadataPtr
    $0.assign(from: UnsafePointer<Any.Type>.init(OpaquePointer(unsafePtr)), count: 1)
}
print(placeholderTypeVar)
print(type(of: structSwiftValue))
```

outputs:

```
NSObject
TestStruct
__SwiftValue
```

The middle one is the answer. And moreover it's identical to result of `type(of: ourStruct)` down to memory level (the `Metadata *` equivalent yielded internally is the very same address!).

More read about metadata which is a very interesting topic in Swift:
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/types-and-meta-types-in-swift-9cd59ba92295
https://kateinoigakukun.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/22/184356
https://medium.com/@weswickwire/creating-a-swift-runtime-library-3cc92fc486cc