# NSStringFromSelector returns variable name instead of variable value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am using the event structure of the netmera analytics tool, it automatically generates code for any even as below.

Unfortunately, according to the structure, it has to get the value of the variable with the selector and when I test it it brings the name of the variable instead of the value of the variable.

Can you please help about this problem.

```
class SearchControlEvent: NetmeraEvent {
    
    @objc let kSearchControlEvent: String = "xyxyxy"
    
    @objc var name: String = "test_data_1"
    @objc var screen: String = "test_data_2"
    @objc var current: String = "test_data_3"
    
    override class func keyPathPropertySelectorMapping() -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
        
        let name = NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.name))
        let screen = NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.screen))
        let current = NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.current))
    
        print(name) // print: name
        print(screen) // print: screen
        print(current) // print: current
        
        return[
            "xxx": NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.name)),
            "yyy": NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.screen)),
            "zzz": NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.current))
        ]
    }
    
    override var eventKey : String {
        let key = NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.kSearchControlEvent))

        print(key) // print: kSearchControlEvent

        return key
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking for `value(forKey:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value
If you need a non-object result (i.e a value type), it's a bit cumbersome to do, but still feasible https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/5329717

Answer (score 1):

`NSStringFromSelector` returns only the string representation of the selector:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395257-nsstringfromselector?language=objc
If you need the value, you need to invoke the selector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please can you give a code example. I want to get the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the property will use the selector under the hood, you dont need to do this explicitly. This should work:

```
override var eventKey : String {
    return self.kSearchControlEvent
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works. However, the keyPathPropertySelectorMapping function cannot be accessed as self.screen

Comment: that function is a Class function, so you'd access it like `let mapping = SearchControlEvent. keyPathPropertySelectorMapping()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the selector:

```
let nameSEL = NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: self.name))
let name = self.performSelector(nameSEL)?.takeUnretainedValue() as? String
```