# When Invoke perform selector to excute function with Int param in swift , I get a unexpected result

Tags: ios, swift

`perform` is NSObjectProtocol's function:

```swift
func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!

func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!

func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object1: Any!, with object2: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
```

This is my code:

```swift
    func test() {
        let sel2 = #selector(newAction(pra:param:))
        perform(sel2, with: 2, with: "bbb")
    }
    
    @objc func newAction(pra: Int, param: String) {
        print("pra = \(pra), param = \(param)") // pra = -5251357295740329306, param = bbb
    }
```

The question [Alternative to performSelector in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714950/13840436) answers the value type can't work by this way.But the `String` and `Int` are implement by struct, why can the `String` work by perform selector?

Comment: What is a guy named `perform()` supposed to do?

Comment: The `perform()` is system function.

Comment: I think it's to do with whether it is a "value type" in ObjC, not whether it is a value type in Swift. `Int` in Swift maps to `NSInteger` in ObjC (which is declared as `typedef long NSInteger`). OTOH, `String` in Swift maps to `NSString` in ObjC.

Comment: If you actually try to call `performSelector` in Objective-C, it doesn't even let you pass in integers as the arguments. Try `[someObject performSelector:@selector(someSelector:) withObject:1 withObject:2];`.

Comment: I try to invoke it in Objective-C, I agree with you.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
func test() {
   let sel2 = #selector(newAction(pra:param:))
   perform(sel2, with: NSNumber(value: 2), with: "bbb")
}

@objc func newAction(pra: NSNumber, param: String) {
    print("pra = \(pra.intValue), param = \(param)")
    // or just
    print("pra = \(pra), param = \(param)")
}
```

Should also work:

```
func test() {
   let sel2 = #selector(newAction(pra:param:))
   perform(sel2, with: 2, with: "bbb")
}

@objc func newAction(pra: NSNumber, param: String) {
    print("pra = \(pra), param = \(param)")
}
```

*The argument type needs to be a reference type. In Swift side, passing an Int to `withObject:` parameter makes that `Int` converted into `NSNumber`.
But the Objective-C runtime does not automatically convert it back to Int. (Remember that Objective-C selectors do not have type information.)*