# Using a system icon in a UIButton, in a UIToolbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to have a button, in a toolbar, use a system icon, by modifying its appearance in the XCode 7 interface builder. If I do this at the toolbar item level, then this just becomes a regular UIButtonBarItem, removing the button underneath. This means it won't send any press items, from what I can see.

I don't see a way on the UIButton, in the interface builder, to specify a system icon. Ideally I would like to avoid having to do this programmatically. Can anyone suggested a way?

Note, Apple [indicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Iconography.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH59-SW1):

> iOS provides a lot of small icons—representing common tasks and types
>   of content—for use in tab bars, toolbars, navigation bars, and Home
>   screen quick actions. It’s a good idea to use the built-in icons as
>   much as possible because users already know what they mean.

Unfortunately it is not clear how to leverage them? Some sources indicate using "iOS-Artwork-Extractor", but I would hope there is another way to address this, maybe via some API call?

XCode 7.2.1, targeting iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the UIButtonBarItem and the subset of icons available there (see table 41-1 in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html)), to have it notify the code that it was pressed, then it is simply a question of adding an 'IBAction' function to the class corresponding to the view, for example (Swift):

```
@IBAction func flashItemActioned (sender: UIButton) {
   //
}
```

and then linking the "sent actions" of the item with the function in the first responder.

For UIButton based implementations I haven't found a solution beyond the "iOS-Artwork-Extractor".

Comment: this worked until xcode 9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36196295/1736679