# Get the frame of UIBarButtonItem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

how could I get the frame of a rightbarbuttonItem in swift? I found this : [UIBarButtonItem: How can I find its frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318368/uibarbuttonitem-how-can-i-find-its-frame) but it says cannot convert NSString to UIView, or cannot convert NSString to String :

```
let str : NSString = "view" //or type String
let theView : UIView = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.valueForKey("view")//or 'str'
```

The goal is to remove the rightBarButtonItem, add an imageView instead, and move it with a fadeOut effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should try it like:

```
var barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!
var buttonItemView = barButtonItem.valueForKey("view")

var buttonItemSize = buttonItemView?.size
```

**Edit (Swift 3):**

```
var barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!
let buttonItemView = barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
var buttonItemSize = buttonItemView?.size
```

Comment: perfect thanks, with a `AnyObject?` to buttonItemView it works fine

Comment: doesn't work with the new SDK and Xcode 8.3.1 Do you have an alternative?

Comment: @JVS  `.valueForKey` returns an Any?. Cast to UIView to make it compile. `var buttonItemSize = (buttonItemView as? UIView).size`

Comment: swift3 like that:   let buttonItemSize = (buttonItemView as! UIView).frame.size

Comment: This seems to be broken in Xcode 9 beta 6 targeting iOS 11... Is anyone else seeing the same?

Comment: This works well in Xcode 10.2.1. It's just called `value(forKey:)` now in Swift 4

Answer (score 5):

In Swift4, XCode9

```
    for view in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
        if let findClass = NSClassFromString("_UINavigationBarContentView") {
            if view.isKind(of: findClass) {
                if let barView = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
                    let barFrame = barView.frame
                    let rect = barView.convert(barFrame, to: view)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Aerox try to call this in viewDidAppear() method

Comment: @Aerox you can also try calling this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but you should be careful to avoid calling it more that it needs to be called.

Answer (score 4):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "myImage"), for: .normal)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(self.customButton.convert(self.customButton.frame, to: nil))
    }
}
```

You must use UIBarButtonItem objects created with `customView` for this; UIBarButtonItem objects created the regular way don't have enough information exposed.  It's important that the frame be looked up ***after*** the parent UINavigationController's UINavigationBar has completely laid out its entire subview tree.  For most use cases, the visible UIViewController's `viewDidAppear` is a good enough approximation of this.