# Getting frame of UIBarButtonItem returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to access the frame of a `UIBarButtonItem` like this:

```
if let items = self.toolbarItems{

        let item = items[1]

        print(item)
        let view = item.value(forKey: "view") as! UIView


    }
```

print(item) returns an existing item. Why is it not possible to get an `UIView` back?

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` isn't a view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991100/get-the-frame-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift

Comment: @rmaddy this is why i access item.value(forKey: "view")

Comment: @TusharSharma this is the sample code I used

Comment: No, you didn't use the code from the mentioned link.
It should look like this:
`let barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!
 let buttonItemView = barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
        
 let buttonItemSize = buttonItemView?.frame.size`

Comment: @kamil3 I was referring to item.value(forKey:"view") as! UIView. it is the same. the rest is ignorable since it isn't the issue.

Answer (score 5):

That's the problem with using undocumented properties. They can change without notice.

Here are the results using Xcode 8.3.1 using the iOS 10 SDK.

```
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView())
let view1 = item1.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
print("\(view1)")
```

prints

```
Optional(<UIView: 0x7f9049001400; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000003cc00>>)
```

However

```
let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Test", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
let view2 = item2.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
print("\(view2)")
```

prints

```
nil
```

---

Even taking this to the next level

```
class MyObject: NSObject { @objc var view: UIView? } // Fake to get selector

let item3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Test", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
let view3 = (item3 as NSObjectProtocol).perform(#selector(getter: MyObject.view))?.takeRetainedValue()
print("\(view3)")
```

prints

```
nil
```

Comment: thanks for Your explanation. However, do You know how to fix this issue in my case? I still need to access the frame.