# Get the View of UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uibarbuttonitem

Hopefully, this is an easy question.  I am trying to obtain the UIView of a UIBarButtonItem.  Looking at the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991100/get-the-frame-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift) I came up with the following code:

```
let notificationButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon_notification.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

let notificationView = notificationButton.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
```

However, notificationView is nil.  So, thoughts on what I failed to interpret from the linked StackOverflow question?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: NRitH: I want to modify the image to add a badge

Comment: Did you added notificationButton  into navigationItem?

Comment: DS Dharma: You don't add the navigationButton into a navigationItem, you assign it like this: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = notificationButton

Answer (score 3):

Starting from iOS 11 this code will not work cause line of code below will not cast UIView. Also it's counting as private API and seems to be will not pass AppStore review.

```
guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }
```

[Thread on: forums.developer.apple](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87823)

Answer (score 1):

So, DS Dharma gave me a idea which ended up working.  The "view" value is only available after it is assigned to the toolbar navigation item like this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon_notification.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.addBadge(number: 0, withOffset: CGPoint(x: 7.0, y: 0.0) , andColor: UIColor.black, andFilled: true)
```

where the addBadge() function needs the UIView.  BTW, if anyone is wondering, the addBadge function was taken from this post:  http://www.stefanovettor.com/2016/04/30/adding-badge-uibarbuttonitem

Highly recommended if you need this piece of functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when you have multiple bar items. e.g. self.navigationItem.rightBarButtomItems.append(barBtn)