# filterBarButton?.value(forKey: "view") is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

**Question**
Using breakpoints, I found that `filterBarButton` is not nil, but the `filterBarButton?.value(forKey: "view")`is nil. The `filterBarButton` should have a view because I assigned it to a button in the `viewDidLoad`. Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

I use the frame of right bar button (the Filter button) to place the triangle image underneath it as shown below. I want the triangle image to be centered and directly underneath the Filter button.
[image]

**Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let filterButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Filter", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filterButtonTapped))
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = filterButton
        setUpFilter()
    }

func setUpFilter() {
     let filterBarButton = navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem
     let btnView = filterBarButton?.value(forKey: "view") as AnyObject
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492213/7327018)

Comment: No, you never assign a view to the bar button item. Why are you trying to did into the private properties of `UIBarButtonItem`? What is your goal?

Comment: I thought I did? In the `viewDidLoad`, `navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = filterButton`

Comment: I use the bar button item frame to place an image in the nav bar

Comment: That assigns a UIBarButtonItem to the navbar. That it no way creates a view in the bar button item itself.

Comment: If you want to add an image then use `UIBarButtonItem(image:style:target:action:)` and add that button to the nav bar.

Comment: @rmaddy I think you misinterpreted what I meant. I updated my answer to clarify!

Comment: The only valid way to get a view from a `UIBarButtonItem` is to create the button using a `customView`. Then you can get that view's frame translated to the navbar's frame.

Comment: okay got it thanks!