# Is it possible to access NavigationBar BarButtons when created in storyboard?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have created in storyboard, a navigation bar with 3 left bar buttons
[image]

and each bar button has its own IBOutlet variable.
Is there a way to access each one and get its coordinates in the navigation bar?
I am just looking for the lower left and right XY values.

I have in code the following line

```
print("bbtnFindMyPics frame size: \(bbtnFindMyPics.accessibilityFrame.size)")
```

but I get the values  (0.0, 0.0).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991100/get-the-frame-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift

Comment: @Faysal Ahmed: Thank you for the msg. It did work a bit, by giving me some insight. The last line of code "var buttonItemSize = buttonItemView?.size" does not work with Swift 5 anymore and it has to be changed to "var buttonItemSize = buttonItemView?.frame.size". However this solution only gives the first barbuttonitem. I need to figure out how to loop through all the left hand side NavigationBar barbuttonitems.